# Deploy Bokeh Plot into Server

Tags: flask, deployment, server, bokeh, holoviews

I have one bokeh plot plot.ipynb i want to deploy this plot into my server , so that i can do dynamic data updation into my plot in my own server deployment .
Can you please tell me what is the best way/easy way to do deployment of my plot into my own server.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
import geoviews as gv
 .......
dd=df_div.opts(width=70, height=70)
dd1=df_div1.opts(width=600, height=90)
dd2=df_div2.opts(width=100,height=10)
finalplot=pn.Column(pn.Row(dd, dd1, dd2), tiles*rasterize(hmap1).options(**opts)*logo1.opts(hooks= 
[absolute_position], apply_ranges=False)).servable()
finalplot
```

I am thinking to :-
 1. convert plot.ipynb file to plot.py .
 2. then run plot.py as a dynamic webpage

Deploying through bokeh server i can do but i am thinking that if i am having all the modules files ( pandas, bokeh , panel etc) files then why not use those modules files , my own server and deploy the plot into my own server instead of first deploying my plot into bokeh serve then my own server as the loading time will get increase.

**But i don't know how to do this deployment 
OR is there any other best / fast way to do plot deployment into my own server with dynamic data behavior .**

Answer (score 0):

In your script I can see you are using `import panel as pn` and you are using `final_plot.servable()`.

If you just want to deploy your notebook quickly to a local server, you can use the command line and go to the directory where this file is located. Then type:
`panel serve your_plot.ipynb`

If you want to do some real deployment then start with the documentation of panel on this:

- https://panel.pyviz.org/user_guide/Deploy_and_Export.html
- https://panel.pyviz.org/user_guide/Server_Deployment.html

There is also an explanation of deploying on Heroku there, which is also a good option if you don't want to do local deployment.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,
But i want to deploy this plot in my own server (IBM HTTP server )